# Calling proc as a hash key in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, proc

Refers to - [bizzare way of calling Procs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385041/bizzare-way-of-calling-procs)

[@BroiSatse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336231/broisatse) thanks a lot for the answer. One additional moment to clarify - what if one needs to pass extra arguments (added to the code as `param_1 and _2`):

```
def callbacks(param_1, param_2, procs)
  procs[:var_1].call(param_1)
  puts "Proceed"
  procs[:var_2].call(param_2)
end

callbacks(arg_1, arg_2, :var_1 => Proc.new {block_1},
         :var_2 => Proc.new {block_2})
```

What goes first? i.e. what will be passed first to execute the `def callbacks`- arguments (`arg_1, arg_2`) in place of params (`param_1, param_2`) or procs (`:var_1, :var_2`)? This is important to know to properly code the params line - `def callbacks(param_1, param_2, procs)`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This should be a comment to the related answer. If it is to be a question, it should be written in a more independent way.

Comment: Sorry I'am new to this forum, but in that topic I got a suggestion to create a new post and not to use answers as new questions.

Comment: Then, as I suggested, write is as an independent question. Don't force the readers to read the other question/answer in order to understand this question. It has nothing to do with being new or old to this site. It is just about how considerate you are.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a response to another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see how you think this will possibly make a difference here, but the arguments are evaluated from left to right and in YARV are pushed onto the stack in that order. Obviously, though, they are all passed before the called method starts executing.